# Json array in array parsing Android

Tags: java, android, json

I was trying to parse JSON (in android) which have an array in array. how can I parse this JSON if I want "0.01601900" (1 row 2 column) please help and thank you in advance.

```
[
[1517045040000, "0.01601900", "0.01602000", "0.01601200", "0.01602000", "15.59000000", 1517045099999, "0.24969503", 11, "8.18000000", "0.13104338", "0"],
[1517045100000, "0.01601300", "0.01608900", "0.01601300", "0.01602500", "154.65000000", 1517045159999, "2.48191231", 52, "105.30000000", "1.69054380", "0"],
[1517045160000, "0.01603000", "0.01606100", "0.01603000", "0.01606000", "78.46000000", 1517045219999, "1.25935145", 42, "70.91000000", "1.13832495", "0"],
[1517045220000, "0.01606000", "0.01606400", "0.01603000", "0.01605100", "33.41000000", 1517045279999, "0.53627978", 31, "25.42000000", "0.40807300", "0"],
[1517045280000, "0.01604100", "0.01606000", "0.01600000", "0.01606000", "159.25000000", 1517045339999, "2.55154418", 45, "27.03000000", "0.43304113", "0"]
]
```

Comment: the java structure is List<List<String>>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
try 
{
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("Your jsonString");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {

                Log.i(" ROW " + i + " Col " + j, ": " + jsonArray1.get(j));
            }

        }
}
catch (JSONException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way I know of (without external libraries), you need to use `JSONArray` to parse it and then go through with `for` loops.

```
String jsonString = "[[1, \"b\", \"c\"]," +
                    "[2, \"e\", \"f\"]," +
                    "[3, \"h\", \"i\"]]";

List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray innerJasonArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
        List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < innerJasonArray.length(); j++) {
            innerList.add(String.valueOf(innerJasonArray.get(j)));
        }
        list.add(innerList);
    }
}catch (JSONException je) {
    Log.e("MYTAG", je.getMessage());
}

Log.e("MYTAG", "list: "+list);
Log.e("MYTAG", "row1,col2: " + list.get(0).get(1));
```